# Google Sheets - Delete rows with characters

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with a sheet that has both numeric and text-values. What I would like to do, is to **remove all the rows with text values and only keep the rows with numeric values**.
In this image, Column A represents what I currently have, Column B what I want to achieve. I have an example code that can be used to remove single values, but how could I make this work to apply for all the characters, not just specific words?

[image]

```js
function deleteEmptyRows(){ 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetData = new Array();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,'')!=''){ targetData.push(data[n])};
    Logger.log(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,''))
  }
  sh.getDataRange().clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
}
```

Also, it doesn't need to be this solution that does the work. I am looking for the best solution. This is just an example I found.

Comment: You can just check if there is a letter using `/[A-Za-z]/.test(string)` and then either drop the line or move on to the next one.

Comment: Thank you. Tried it out but not sure how to include it to the code, so I get the following error:  
ReferenceError: string is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example it could look like this:

```
function deleteEmptyRows(){ 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetData = new Array();
  for(var n = 0; n < data.length; n++){
    var cell = data[n][0].toString().replace(/-/g,'') // remove dashes
    if (!isNaN(cell)) targetData.push(data[n]); // if the content looks like a number
  }
  sh.getDataRange().clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said it doesn't need to be a solution that uses script? Then maybe you can use `QUERY()` with the `matches()` clause?

```
=QUERY(A1:A,"where A matches '\d+(?:-\d+)?'",0)
```

I'm not sure about the use of the current regular expression, but it does the correct matching for your currently shown sample data where:

- `\d+` - 1+ digits.
- `(?:-\d+)?` - An optional non-capture group where a single hyphen is followed by 1+ digits.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I meant it doesn't need to be exactly this solution but it should be a solution that uses script. But thanks still!